# How to convert all "LF" chars to "<br />" tag and show it on the HTML page

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

How to convert all `LF` chars to `<br />` tags and show it on the HTML page?

I have the following example XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="data.xslt"?>
<data>
<lines>
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
</lines>
</data>
```

and I want to show all lines on the HTML page. For this I use the following XSLT transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:variable name="filtered">
                    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="./data/lines"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="search" select="'&#xA;'"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="new"><br /></xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <td align="left">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$filtered" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </td>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="replace">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:param name="search"/>
        <xsl:param name="new"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($string, $search)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $search)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$new"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $search)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="search" select="$search"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="new" select="$new"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I open that XML file in Firefox (I use browser to show XSLT transformation) I will see that result:

```
Line 1Line 2Line 3Line 4Line 5Line 6
```

As you see, `LF` chars were not replaced by `<br />` tags.

But when I use other string, for example `EOL`:

```
<xsl:with-param name="new">EOL</xsl:with-param>
```

I will see expected result:

```
EOLLine 1EOLLine 2EOLLine 3EOLLine 4EOLLine 5EOLLine 6EOL
```

The problem is with the convert/display `<br />` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a node fragment as a parameter value, as you do with `<xsl:with-param name="new"><br /></xsl:with-param>`, but to output that as a `br` element in your template you need to use `<xsl:copy-of select="$new"/>`, not `xsl:value-of`.

[edit] Here is an example: http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2012062801.xml. The stylesheet is at http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2012062801.xsl, I will also include it below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.01" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
              <title>Example</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:variable name="filtered">
                    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="data/lines"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="search" select="'&#xA;'"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="new"><br /></xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <div>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$filtered"/>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="replace">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:param name="search"/>
        <xsl:param name="new"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($string, $search)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $search)"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$new"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $search)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="search" select="$search"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="new" select="$new"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: could you show me how to do it exactly? I tested `<xsl:copy-of select="$new"/>` but I does not work fo me (in FF browser) :-/ Maybe I do something wrong :-/ You can use [XML Playground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/Y4VkXW) made by banana to show it.

Comment: @zajjar - If you're trying to run your xslt in FF, you should change your version to 1.0 so you don't get valid XSLT 2.0 answers like Sean B. Durkin's.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a sample XSLT stylesheet and a link to a working online sample.

Comment: @Martin Now I see were is the problem. I changed `<xsl:value-of select="$new"/>` on `<xsl:copy-of select="$new"/>` but you changed also `<xsl:value-of select="$filtered" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` on `<xsl:copy-of select="$filtered"/>` and it is the main difference! Thank you for your good example, everything is clear now :-) Your answer is correct as well and I think that it is the best solution to my problem, because we get rid of `disable-output-escaping="yes"` argument and also we get rid of problems wit FF. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You have extra quotes in your parameter value.  Try changing the line...</strike>

```
<xsl:with-param name="search" select="'&#xA;'"/>
```

To...

```
<xsl:with-param name="search" select="&#xA;"/>
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by the OP, the above is incorrect and will cause an XSLT transformation error.
I believe the answer by @banana to be the correct one.

Comment: Have you tried it? When I do it I see "XSLT transformation error" :-/ Extra qotes are necessary here.

Comment: @zajjar, no I hadn't tried it, as I was confident it would fix it. I have tried it now, and it worked (at least on the XSLT1.0 I'm using).  Try in lower case `&#xa;` instead to see if that makes any difference

Comment: There is no problem with search "LF" char in my example, because it works. As you see in my second example I have succesuflly replaced "LF" char to "EOL" string. Problem is only with show/convert etc. "<br />" tag.

Comment: @zajjar, I have been playing, and you are correct that the quotes are necessary. The only combination I could get to work was using the answer from banana (encoding the `<br/>`)... [have a look here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/Y4VkXW)

Comment: yes, "banana" answer is correct. It seems that problem is with Firefox XSLT intrpreter :-/

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, xsl:anaylze-string is the perfect fit for this problem. This XSLT 2.0 style-sheet run under Saxon ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:so="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222334"
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl fn xs so x">

<xsl:output method="xhtml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"
            doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
            doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/></head>
  <body>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="data/lines"/>
  </body>
 </html> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="lines">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\n">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <br />
          <xsl:value-of select="'&#x0A;'" />
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... when applied to this input document ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
<lines>
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
</lines>
</data>
```

... will produce this html page ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   </head>
   <body><br />
      Line 1<br />
      Line 2<br />
      Line 3<br />
      Line 4<br />
      Line 5<br />
      Line 6<br />

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but but there is a lot of problems with your solution :-( Maybe it works under Saxon but not in FF and JAXP as well. Try to do it and you will see :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
<xsl:with-param name="new"><br /></xsl:with-param>
```

with:

```
<xsl:with-param name="new">&lt;br /&gt;</xsl:with-param>
```

Comment: This is not what I expect :-/ With this "<br />" tag is escaped and it is displayed in HTML like that: "<br />Line 1<br />Line 2<br />Line 3<br />Line 4<br />Line 5<br />Line 6<br />". But I want to have "line break" instead of that. You know, I want to see line after line and no "<br />" string.

Comment: Have you tried it? For me it is displayed with line breaks and not with <br/> strings.

Comment: @zajjar - as I put in the latest comment on my answer, this looks like the correct solution... [have a look at this xmlplayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/Y4VkXW)

Comment: @banana I have tried it once again, and firefox show it in wrong way :-/ I attach a screenshot and you can see it [screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/85/picem.png/) It is not what I expect :-( Maybe some changes are needed in "<xsl:output>" or FF interprets it differently? Please, try it in Firefox 13.

Comment: @banana I have just tested it in Java JAXP and result is exactly as I expect! It looks that problem is with Firefox XSLT intrpreter. It just ignores argument `disable-output-escaping="yes"` and it is always set to "no" (!?). Thank you very much for your help. Your answer is correct.

Comment: @banana There is a [Mozilla bug 98168](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98168) and it is a problem.

Comment: @zajjar I've checked it before in IE, now I see that in FF it doesn't work.  If my answer helped you please mark as answer. thank you!

Comment: It is true that Mozilla Firefox does not support disable-output-escaping but in your case it is not needed, you can pass around a result tree fragment like a `br` element node as a parameter value and then output a `br` element in the HTML result, only you need to use `<xsl:copy-of select="$paramName"/>`, not value-of, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this will write current node value replacing \n with <br/>

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\n', '&lt;br/&gt;')"/>
```

Comment: It works only with XPath 2.0. Firefox does not have this function.